# Time to decimal time in Python

Tags: python, time

Which Python datetime or time method should I use to convert time in HH:MM:SS to decimal time in seconds?  The times represent durations of time (most are less than a minute) and are not connected to a date.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
t = "1:12:23"
(h, m, s) = t.split(':')
result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
```

Answer (score 14):

If by "decimal time" you mean an integer number of seconds, then you probably want to use `datetime.timedelta`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> hhmmss = '02:29:14'
>>> [hours, minutes, seconds] = [int(x) for x in hhmmss.split(':')]
>>> x = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
>>> x
datetime.timedelta(0, 8954)
>>> x.seconds
8954
```

(If you actually wanted a `Decimal`, of course, it's easy enough to get there...)

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(x.seconds)
Decimal('8954')
```

Comment: But n.b. that if there is a microsecond component this will truncate it.

Comment: @JohnBachir possibly this was true at the time the comment was written but at least in my environment on python 3.10 today, that is no longer the case; `import datetime; a = datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 9, 22, 18, 49, 700000); b = datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 9, 22, 18, 49, 811111); print((b - a).microseconds)` yields `111111` for me.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `datetime` module:

```
>>> t = datetime.time(12,31,53)
>>> ts = t.hour * 3600 + t.minute * 60 + t.second
>>> print ts
45113
```

Comment: Or if you require finer resolution than 1 s: `ts = t.hour * 3600 + t.minute * 60 + t.second + t.microsecond / 1000 / 1000`