# Get time values with a slider/scale

Tags: python, time, pygtk

I'm coding a video player with controls that allow the user to select beginning and end time to crop/trim it. At run-time, I read the total length of the media file.

I have a "play" HScale, that updates while playing, and allow the user to seek, this is fine.

But I need two others: Beginning, and end. Let's suppose the media file is 00:02:42 long (that would be 162 in [decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098248/time-to-decimal-time-in-python)) so I'd like to setup a `GTK.HScale()` (this is a generic, almost purely math logic - at which I'm pretty bad - question, the environment is not so important) that goes from 00:00:00 to 00:02:42.

Then, when the user moves the "beginning/start" slider (in increments of one second) and click a button, I would then retrieve the value (either hh:mm:ss, or decimal and then convert back to hh:mm:ss, no problem.) of the slider along the timeline.

My full code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/philipyassin/derusher/src/83689c55aa0654f928ef3d6117dc33dfcfabc933/derusher.py?fileviewer=file-view-default), I'm stuck in [the docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkadjustment.html#constructor-gtkadjustment), thank you for helping!

Comment: What's the exact quesiton here? Do you want to know how to convert seconds into a "hh:mm:ss" format?