# Take user input in HH:MM and convert it to a float

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I am trying to create a program where I add number of hours worked into a list then sum inputs and calculate overtime for hours worked above 40

```
from tkinter import *


#Tkinter window
win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")
win.title("Attempt")
win.resizable(False,False)
my_list =[]


#Get input(shift hours)
def inp():
    
    for _ in range(1):
        my_list.append(float(actinp.get()))
        
        showlabel.config(text=((my_list)))

#Calculate overtime for +40 hours
def show():
    rate =(int(rateinp.get()))
    a40=float(sum(my_list)-40)
    showlabel.config(text=(a40*rate*0.5))

#Clear the list/screen
def clear ():
    my_list.clear()
    showlabel.config(text=" ")

#Remove the last input from list/screen
def pop():
    my_list.pop()        
    showlabel.config(text=(my_list))


#Tkinter widgets
kk=Label(win, width=70, height=1)
kk.grid()
showlabel=Label(win, width=71, height=10, bg='white')
showlabel.grid()
actlab=Label(win, text="Number of hours")
actlab.grid()
actinp=Entry(win, width=5)
actinp.grid()
ratelab=Label(win,text="Rate")
ratelab.grid()
rateinp=Entry(win,width=5)
rateinp.grid()
actbtn=Button(win, width=5, text="Add", command=inp)
actbtn.grid()
clrbtn=Button(win,text="Clear",command=clear)
clrbtn.grid()
delbtn=Button(win,width=5, text="Delete", command=pop)
delbtn.grid()
bttt=Button(win, width=10, text="Calculate", command=show)
bttt.grid(padx=23)




win.mainloop()
```

I am only able to do this by taking a float input, but I need the input to be collected in HH:MM format, then switch it to a float to use it with the math in the other function.

example:
Input: [11:30, 4:42, 5:07]  - switch to: [11.5, 4.70, 5.13]

Comment: Conversion from "HH:MM" to float number is not that hard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time to decimal time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098248/time-to-decimal-time-in-python)

Comment: @Abdo Proff. Are we taking three 11:30, 4:42, 5:07 in input or just one at time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert input "HH:MM" (`actinp.get()`) to float number (`hours`):

- split the string using `h, m = actinp.get().strip().split(":")`
- calculate the hours using `hours = int(h) + round(int(m)/60, 2)`

Below is the updated `inp()`:

```py
def inp():
    try:
        # get the hours and minutes in string
        h, m = actinp.get().strip().split(":")
        # convert the input hours and minutes to hours in float number
        hours = int(h) + round(int(m)/60, 2)
        my_list.append(hours)
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)
    showlabel.config(text=my_list)
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this is exactly what I needed to advance with this little program sir.
Thank you very much for all your kind help everyone!